# Getting 404 Not found error but page is rendered correctly - spa nuxt app

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3, frontend, nuxt.js

I am building a simple app (spa) using nuxt 2.x.

Directory looks like..

```
pages
 users/
   index.vue
   _id/
     index.vue

 index.vue
```

`/users` for list of users and `/users/:id` for single user's detail page.
(I call lambda function to get data btw)

**I did**

```
nuxt generate
```

and put whatever created inside /dist into S3.

**Here's my problem.**

Whenever I open `/user/:id` page,
I see `404 Not found` error on the console but the page renders with no problem.

I thin.. since `nuxt generate` only creates non-dynamic route and therefore there's no such a html file inside S3 when `/user/xxx` page is called, it's giving 404 error.

but of course js files are there so the pages are rendered correctly.

(correct me if im wrong).

I researched and found that I can manually create dynamic route but I do not think that method would solve the fundamental issue. (because..once new user registers, detail page for that user does not exist inside S3 and it will give the 404 error as before)

**what I want to ask:**

- Is there way to remove this error?
- Is it a bad idea to put things inside S3 (i.e. create static site) for this kind of website?

---

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
import {NuxtConfig} from '@nuxt/types';
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const envSet = require(`./config/env.${environment}`);
const config: NuxtConfig = {
  ssr: false,
  target: 'static',
  srcDir: './src/',
  env: envSet,

  server: {
    port: 3333,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
  },
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - test',
    title: 'test',
    meta: [{charset: 'utf-8'}, {name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1'}, {hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: ''}],
    link: [{rel: 'icon', type: 'image/png', href: '/favicon.png'}],
  },

  generate: {
    dir: '../back/assets',
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: `${envSet.BASE_URL}/api_v1`,
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: ['@/plugins/nuxt-client-init', '@/plugins/axios', '@/plugins/amplify', '@/plugins/filters', '@/plugins/day'],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/typescript
    '@nuxt/typescript-build',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/axios'],

  // Vuetify module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify)
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  },

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    transpile: ['vuetify/lib'],

    filenames: {
      chunk: ({isDev}) => (isDev ? '[name].js' : '[id].[chunkhash].js'),
    },
    terser: {
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        },
      },
    },
    parallel: true,
    extend(config, ctx) {
      if (ctx.isDev) {
        config.devtool = '#source-map';
      }
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        if (config.module) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
            //loader: 'eslint-loader',
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          });
        }
      }
    },
  },

  router: {
    middleware: 'auth',
  },

  typescript: {
    typeCheck: true,
    ignoreNotFoundWarnings: true,
  },
};

export default config;
```

Comment: What is the value of your `target`? Mind share your `nuxt.config.js` please?

Comment: Also, does it work locally if you `yarn generate && yarn start`?

Comment: target is static.

Comment: let me add nuxt config in my post. when I yarn start locally, I do not get 404 error.

Comment: What is you use `_id.vue` rather than nesting an `index.vue` inside of it? Which route do you see when you `yarn generate`?

Comment: Also, can you upload it to https://app.netlify.com/drop and see if it works there?

Comment: I think there's no difference. `_id/index.vue` also creates route {name:"user-id", path:"/user/:id"} when `yarn generate`

Comment: Was essentially to be sure that nothing was messed up here.

Comment: So, did you tried this on Netlify?

Comment: hi, no I haven't. There's already lots of code and I do not want to put everything in there.. so I have to simplify it. maybe I will try on weekends. Btw, I found that I was using `<a :href="/user/{id}"></a>` for page transition. After I change that to `<nuxt-link :to="/user/{id}"></nuxt-link>` I no longer get 404 error. Of course, if I try to reload that detail page, I get 404 error though. @kissu